# win10: Computer wakes up immediately when i put it to hibernation

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

In the past 2 weeks my pc immediately wakes up when i put it to hibernation, but only once, if i do it a second time right after it works just fine.

There is no logged event other then some kernel events for the immediate wake up. Only when it has successfully gone to hibernation the second time and i wake it using mouse or keybord do i get a power-troubleshooter event with the typical unknown wake source.

Its a self built mid-tower i built in 2019, and it was formatted about 4 months ago.

Comment: Try `powercfg -lastwake` directly after this happens and it wakes up again to see what woke it up.

Comment: And this tells me what? "wake history count - 0"

Comment: If a powerevent caused by software woke the computer, powercfg -lastwake will tell you what it is. So you ruled out its a power event that wakes up the computer, and its something else, such as a magic packet (wol), or USB device such as mouse or keyboard that somehow registers its wakeup.

Comment: Which i have also ruled out, hence why im here asking

Comment: Iv been trying to find out what triggers it, but other then having the pc on for a few hours i have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar  same issue and managed to fix with the following procedure.

In the settings of your computer network card, switch to "power management" tab, and check that, if the 2nd setting (*"allow this device to wake the computer"*) is set, the 3rd (*"Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer"*) is also set :

[image: Network Power properties]

Comment: This is the first i turn off on every computer iv ever owned, since this is infamous for waking the computer up.